# using require to display image in vue causing vue app to rerender

Tags: vue.js

```
        <div class="bottom-container">
            <p >All the images</p>

            <div  v-for="(curImg,index) in ary" :key="index" >
                <img :src="getImage(curImg)" alt="cup-img">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is getImage method:

```
    methods: {
        getImage (imgSrc) {
            let imgNameArr = imgSrc.split('\\');
            let imgName = imgNameArr[imgNameArr.length - 1];
            return require(`../../../results/cups/${imgName}`);
        }
}
```

I am using axios to get a list or name exist in the cups folder and trying to display them .
The image can be display at first and then at some point, the component get rerender .  The issue same happen in the require part in getImage() method, Since, If I do not use require, it would not cause component to rerender.
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem!